# Peewee to print generated queries

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

Is there a way or setting in Peewee where I can get it to print out all the queries being executed in order to debug and understand potential performance issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is **documented**: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#logging-queries

```
# Print all queries to stderr.
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```